# Is it possible to estimate how many digits are accurate in 32 bit floats?

Tags: floating-point, cpu

I guess I understand what precision means in floating points, since you can only rely on what is stored in the mantissa.

If I understand it right, if you add 0.000001 100000 times to 0, an error can start to build up.

Is there a way to prevent this error, to anticipate it or to mitigate it by using less digits in a 32 bit float ?

EDIT: for example, in starcraft 2, only unit orders are communicated, game states are not. Still all players view the same thing. Floating point errors build up are avoided, but how, at what cost or constraint ?

Comment: Maybe they use integers?

Comment: What ? I highly doubt it

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a single operation in properly implemented floating point and the rounding mode is round-to-nearest (the most common), the error is at most one-half the distance between representable numbers. This is because, in round-to-nearest mode, operations return the representable result that is nearest to the exact mathematical result. (This is called “correct rounding”.)

This includes operations such as converting numerals (such as “0.000001” or “1e-5”) to floating point. However, some operations, notably library routines for complicated operations such as sine or logarithm, typically do not always return correctly rounded results (due to the difficulty of doing so). Thus, you must check the specifications for your implementation before relying on error bounds.

32-bit IEEE 754 floating point uses a sign bit, eight exponent bits (representing normal exponents [of 2] from -126 to 127), and 23 explicit significand bits. (The proper term is significand. A mantissa is a fractional part of a logarithm.) The full significand has 24 bits because there is an implicit leading one (except for subnormal numbers, below 2<sup>-126</sup> in magnitude). Thus, the distance between a representable number and the next higher representable number is 2<sup>-23</sup> times the value of the leading one bit. That value is, of course, the highest power of two that is not greater than the number. (E.g., for 5, the leading bit has value 4, so the least significant bit has value 4•2<sup>-23</sup> = 2<sup>-21</sup>. Thus, if an exact mathematical result of a single operation would be around 5, the maximum error would be 2<sup>-22</sup>.)

When you perform multiple operations, the error is hugely dependent upon the operations performed and the values involved. Careful analysis must be performed to determine error bounds. Depending on the operations, it is possible for errors to combine and to be magnified, so that errors can even become infinite.

Note that if you attempt to add 0.000001 100,000 times, you will have two kinds of errors. First, 0.000001 is not exactly representable in binary floating point, so there is an error in the operation of converting that numeral to floating point. Second, each addition may have a rounding error.

You also mention maintaining identical information in different processes. This is a separate, although overlapping, problem from bounding error. If the processes are running on identical platforms, it might not be difficult to keep them synchronized, by making them all perform identical operations with identical data, using identical hardware and libraries. This is because floating-point errors are generally not random; performing the same operations on the same data will always return the same results. (Some problem may occur when hardware or library behavior is not fully specified and is permitted to depend on unrelated data, although this tends to be more of a theoretical concern than a problem in practice.) Note that identical platforms means completely identical. Something as small as using a different version of the otherwise same library can produce different results.

If processes are running on different platforms, it can be difficult to keep them synchronized. Even if running with software compiled from identical sources, the compiler may implement the high-level language using different choices of floating-point operations. Among the most notorious is using more precision than the high-level language requires, which some languages permit.

Clause 11 of the IEEE 754-2008 standard has information about producing reproducible floating-point results. Computing platforms might not provide the necessary guarantees to support this.

Answer (score 0):

### To prevent

Use a multi-precision floating-point library (binary or decimal depending if it is important to you that decimal constants are always represented accurately), or an implementation of rational numbers.

### To anticipate

This is the art of [numerical stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability). There are basic principles, but keeping them in mind when programming is not always easy. Consider the example of [solving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance#A_better_algorithm) a quadratic equation.

### Mitigate it by using less digits in a 32 bit float

When you say “digits” you likely mean decimal digits. The first thing to understand about binary floating-point is that it is represented in binary and that it causes confusion to think in terms of decimal digits.

To answer that part more directly, hiding some precision only masks the issues, it does not fix them. It is almost always a bad idea.

---

Regarding your StarCraft 2 example, one typical superstition about IEEE 754 floating-point is that it is not deterministic, as if it could give different results on two computers doing the same computations (say, two StarCaft 2 clients in a network game). Well, IEEE 754 is deterministic. The floating-point computations differ slightly from the same computations done with real numbers, but the computations are always the same for two successive runs or for two different computers running the same binary, as long as the processors on each computer correctly implement the IEEE 754 standard (which they basically do).

Comment: So did blizzard need to be careful about their calculations or not at all ? I'm a little confused now. Maybe it means they made the game use a pre-determined small but large enough time period tick to sequentiate the time orders are sent, instead of directly processing orders, since latency can vary. I guess it only happens in game with such kind of networking model, and not in others.